# Why is my popover textarea + data-binded text empty, knockout.js + bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I want to show a popover with text within a textarea that the user can select.  I have no problem getting the text area to show, but I cannot get my data-binded text to show.  What am I missing?

HTML

```
    <a class="shareVidBtn" data-toggle="popover" data-bind="attr: { 'data-title': $$.LR.Title,'data-content':'<textarea class=input-block-level  data-bind=attr:{text:'+$$.paths.root+'/Page?ID='+ID()+'}></textarea>'}" rel="popover" data-html="true">
```

JS

```
      $("[rel='popover']").popover();
```

Thanks!

**SOLUTION** (thanks to Posthuma for a point in the right direction)

```
    <a class="shareVidBtn" data-toggle="popover" data-bind="attr: { 'data-title': $$.LR.Title, 'data-content': '<textarea class=input-block-level></textarea>' }, shareVid:$$.paths.root + 'Page?ID=' + ID()" rel="popover" data-html="true">
```

Knockout custom binding

```
     ko.bindingHandlers.shareVid = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                setTimeout(function () { 
                    $(element).click(function(){
                        $(this).parent().children().last().find('textarea').val(value);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are appending in the textarea doesn't exist on the DOM when you apply bindings.

You will need to apply bindings to this element, or handle this through a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html).

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't need to use a custom binding, I've only done one and I'm not sure why but I find them really confusing.  I'll give it a go and post my results.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out, check the OP for how I did it.  Thanks for the guidance